# Time series regression by group with Newey-West standard errors in R

Tags: r, plyr, zoo, standard-error

First, I apologize if this question has been answered already. This is my first post on stackoverflow.

I have a panel of stock market data that is structured as in this working example:

```
d <- data.frame(Time = rep(seq.Date( Sys.Date(), length=10, by="day" )),
    Stock = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=10 ),
    x1 = rep(sample(10:30, 10), 3),
    x2 = rep(sample(10:30, 10), 3),
    x3 = rep(sample(10:30, 10), 3))
```

Basically I want to estimate a time series regression with x1 as the dependent variable and as regressors x3 and the lag and lead of x2. I want to perform this for each stock in the sample using Newey West standard errors.

After going to several posts here, I’ve managed to come up with the following:

since I'm working with time series and want to use lag and lead operators, I’ve read that I should use the `zoo` or `xts` format (I’ve chosen the `zoo` format because this is compatible with the `dyn$lm` function which I want to use):

```
d.z <- zoo(data.matrix(d[-1]), d$Time)
```

Note that I transform the Stock column to numeric because the `zoo` package requires all numeric variables.

However, this brings up an error message:

```
Warning message:
In zoo(data.matrix(d[-1]), d$Time):some methods for “zoo” objects do not work 
if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique.
```

I figured this is no problem since ultimately I want to estimate regressions for each stock separately, which would resolve the problem.

To this object I then want to estimate the regression in myLm for each stock.

```
myLm <- function(formula,df) {
temp.lm <- dyn$lm(formula,data=df)
temp.summ <- summary(temp.lm)
temp.summ$coefficients <- unclass(coeftest(temp.lm, vcov. = NeweyWest))
lmOut<-data.frame(t(temp.summ$coefficients))
return(lmOut)}
```

Using the `plyr` package I try to split up the function by stock:

```
outDf <- ddply(d.z, "Stock", function(df)  myLm(x1 ~ lag(x2, -1) + lag(x2, +1) + x3, df))
```

Unfortunately, this brings up another error:

```
Error in eval.quoted(.variables, data) : 
envir must be either NULL, a list, or an environment.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include your library calls in questions when not using base functionality.

in the question `myLm` computes a `summary` but then throws it away so we omit that part.

To perform the computation, split up the data frame and then convert each component of the split to zoo separately.  We used the data.table package here but you could alternately use plyr, dplyr or `by`:

```
library(data.table)
library(dyn) # this pulls in zoo
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)

# test data as in question but use set.seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(Time = rep(seq.Date( Sys.Date(), length=10, by="day" )),
    Stock = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=10 ),
    x1 = rep(sample(10:30, 10), 3),
    x2 = rep(sample(10:30, 10), 3),
    x3 = rep(sample(10:30, 10), 3))

mycoeftest <- function(fo, data) {
   fm <- dyn$lm(fo, read.zoo(data))
   unlist(as.data.frame(unclass(coeftest(fm, vcov. = NeweyWest))))
}

fo <- x1 ~ lag(x2, c(-1, 1)) + x3
data.table(d)[, as.list(mycoeftest(fo, .SD)), by = d$Stock]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly! Could you elaborate a bit more  why the `unlist` and the `as.list` are necessary? I'm quite new to R. Btw: I would upvote your response but I don't have enough reputation points at this moment.

Comment: `unlist` flattens its argument into a vector but data.table will regard a vector as a single column so we apply `as.list` so that data.table regards each component of the vector as a separate column.